# Group By Month And Show Total Days Remaining

Tags: mysql

I want to list grouped by month and the days remaining to complete the course in the next column. The Course has 10 days.

Example data

```
ID Name Date 
1 Sandy 2015-05-06 
2 Candy 2015-05-06 
3 Sandy 2015-05-28 
4 Candy 2015-05-29
5 Candy 2015-06-01
```

Preferred output

```
| Name | Month | Attended | Remaining|
| Sandy| May   |   2      |     8    |
| Candy| May   |   2      |     8    |
| Candy| June  |   1      |     7    |
```

If I use GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m'), Name and try to do the calculation it does not work.

Comment: How do you calculate the days remaining (logically, not in SQL, obviously :-))?

Comment: Total Days is 10.  So the remaining days for Sandy and Candy is 8 and 7.

Comment: Missed that sentence, how embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: Come on, show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two different aggregates:

1. The number of days attended in the current month for a given user.
2. The number of days attended in all months up to and including the current month for a given user.

That's a tad fiddly, so 'tis time to do some Test-Driven Query Design (TDQD).

The table in the question is anonymous — that's such a common and irritating situation.  So, the table is henceforth `CourseAttendance`, with the three columns shown in the data (ID, Name, Date).

#### Number of days attended by user in a specific month

Assuming the expression `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')` is syntactically valid, and that neither `Date` nor `Month` as a column name causes problems, then:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') AS Month,
       Name,
       COUNT(*) AS NumDays
  FROM CourseAttendance
 GROUP BY Month, Name
```

This should produce:

```
Month     Name      NumDays
2015-05   Sandy     2
2015-05   Candy     2
2015-06   Candy     1
```

#### Number of days attended by user up to and including a specific month

This time, the aggregate has to be over all dates less than or equal to the converted month value:

```
SELECT D.Month, D.Name, SUM(C.NumDays) AS TotDays
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') AS Month, Name
          FROM CourseAttendance
       ) AS D
  JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') AS Month,
               Name,
               COUNT(*) AS NumDays
          FROM CourseAttendance
         GROUP BY Month, Name
       ) AS C
    ON C.Month <= D.Month AND C.Name = D.Name
 GROUP BY D.Month, D.Name
```

This should give the output:

```
Month     Name      NumDays
2015-05   Sandy     2
2015-05   Candy     2
2015-06   Candy     3
```

#### Assembling the final result

The two previous result tables need to be joined on Month and Name, to yield the result:

```
SELECT A.Name, A.Month, A.NumDays AS Attended, (10 - B.TotDays) AS Remaining
  FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') AS Month,
               Name,
               COUNT(*) AS NumDays
          FROM CourseAttendance
         GROUP BY Month, Name
       ) AS A
  JOIN (SELECT D.Month, D.Name, SUM(C.NumDays) AS TotDays
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') AS Month, Name
                  FROM CourseAttendance
               ) AS D
          JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') AS Month,
                       Name,
                       COUNT(*) AS NumDays
                  FROM CourseAttendance
                 GROUP BY Month, Name
               ) AS C
            ON C.Month <= D.Month AND C.Name = D.Name
         GROUP BY D.Month, D.Name
       ) AS B
    ON A.Month = B.Month AND A.Name = B.Name
 ORDER BY A.Name, A.Month
```

This should give output like:

```
Name      Month      Attended     Remaining
Candy     2015-05    2            8
Candy     2015-06    1            7
Sandy     2015-05    2            8
```

You can fettle the month value into a month name if you need to.  You can also fettle the sort order if you want month and name within month, etc.

Comment: You solution works but when the dates are entered in a wrong way it gives a wrong answer. The below solution by @salman-a gives the right answer.

Comment: What are you doing allowing invalid dates into a database?  What type are you using to store dates?  The type should be the native DATE type (or a variant of that), and there should be no question of 'dates entered in a wrong way'.  You are setting yourself up for endless problems and subtle failures if you do not use a date type to store date information.

Comment: You solution works but when the dates are entered in a wrong way it gives a wrong answer. The below solution by @salman-a gives the right answer. Your Result - Sandy - 2013 - June - 1 - 8. Salam-a Result : Sandy - 2013 - June - 1 - 9

Comment: Dates were not entered in a proper order. That's what i meant by in a wrong way.

Comment: Curious: there is no data for Sandy in June, and none of my sample outputs include a result for Sandy in June, so I'm puzzled to know what's going wrong — you seem to be using different data than you gave in the question.  If you add a new data sample (add, not replace) to the question, along with your expected output from that sample, I'll take a look at it.  But don't even think of using erroneously formatted dates in the database; it would be downright stupid to allow invalid data into a database.  It is hard enough managing data when it is accurate. Deliberately allowing inaccurate data…!!

Comment: Your code works perfect fine without Join. I used z.Supervisor_Name in the first select and join in the second last sentence... just before the order.